# How to handle hundreds of textarea using tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am trying to make a database CRUD PHP page, which may have 100s of textareas, depending on rows & columns of MySql Table.

For some reasons (viz. faster editing), I am loading 100 rows at a time (my table has ~20,000 rows)

Page loads completely ok, if I use normal textareas.

But, when I use TinyMCE, it becomes unresponsive or loads very slowly, I think because of too many iframes to be created.

So, I was thinking **if there is any way to load the page normally at first. And then,** -

- **attach TinyMCE editor to only specific textarea later, when it gets
  focus, or an edit button for the specific row is clicked.**
- **detach tinyMCE editor, when the textarea lost focus/blur, or save
  button is clicked.**

At present, I am using following (default) script in the `<head>` -

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        width: 550,
        height: 30,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
            "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
        ],
        content_css: "css/content.css",
        toolbar: "insertfile bold italic | subscript superscript | bullist numlist | link image | media fullpage | forecolor backcolor",
        style_formats: [
            {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
            {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
            {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
            {title: 'Table styles'},
            {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ],
        setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('change', function() {
                tinymce.triggerSave();
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

p.s. - I know, both parts of my question, are too vague, but I really couldn't find anything for this to work.

Comment: Doesn't inline editing an option? http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php

Comment: @A.Wolff I just read about it, after your mention, haven't tried it yet, but a small query - **Doesn't it will also make 100 tinymce instances and make page load slow, same as case of textarea. Or does it dynamically attach-detach tinymce to div, after page load is finished.** Asked here, because I couldn't find the difference between using normal tinymce or inline, except that former works on textarea and later one on divs.

Comment: I don't know tinyMCE but i hope it will create only one instance at once, really not sure. This should be tested with thousand textareas. **EDIT:** Just checked but inline editor doesn't seem to work on TEXTAREA  :(

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for your reply. I will test it now. I asked prior to testing, because, I am new to it, re-writing the code for divs in place of textareas is little bit harder for me than others.

Comment: I am also looking for better alternative as my page has to many tinymce editors. I am using inline editor option but it does not work like one editor switching between others. It creates as many editor instance as the number of DIV and makes the page slow.